# How to delete an item from a list using vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, axios

I am trying to build a book directory using vanilla javascript and `axios`. What I want is that every time I press the delete button the book will be deleted from the list. But every time I press the button it shows an error. I don't know where is the problem.

My `app.js` file:

```
 const delBtn = [...document.querySelectorAll(".del-btn")];

  delBtn.map((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     const idValue =
        e.currentTarget.parentElement.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling
           .nextElementSibling.innerHTML;

     try {
        const res = await axios.delete(`/api/books/${Number(idValue)}`);

        const data = res.data.find((book) => book.id === Number(idValue));

        if (!data) {
           console.log(`No book with such${idValue}`);
        }
        const filteredBook = books.filter((book) => {
           if (book.id !== Number(idValue)) {
              const { title, author, image, desc, id } = book;
              return `
              <div class="card flex" style="width: 18rem; min-height:24rem;">
                    <img
                    src=${image}
                    class="card-img-top w-50 rounded mx-auto d-block"
                    alt="#"
                     />
                  <div class="card-body">
                 <h4 class="card-title">${title}</h4>
                 <h6>Written by: <span class="text-primary">${author}</span></h6>
                 <p>${id}</p>
               <p class="card-text"> ${desc}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        <a
           class="btn btn-danger del-btn"
           type="submit"
           ">Delete</a>
     </div>
     </div>  
        `;
           }
        });
        card.innerHTML = filteredBook;
     } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error");
     }
  });
```

My `server.js` file:

```
app.delete("/api/books/:id", (req, res) => {
const { id } = req.params;

const book = books.find((book) => book.id === Number(id));

 if (!book) {
   return res
     .status(400)
     .json({ success: false, msg: `No book with the id of ${id}` });
 }

 const newBook = books.filter((book) => book.id !== Number(id));
 return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: newBook });
  });

app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log("Server is running on port 5000...");
});
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#del-btn")` does not make a lot of sense. Id attribute values must be unique, so that's only ever going to retrieve one element (or none).

Comment: You should give your "delete" buttons a *class* instead of an id. A class can appear on multiple elements; an id cannot.

Comment: the error that I got comes from here : catch (error) {
            console.log("Error");
         }

Comment: I changed it its still the same.

Comment: And, what exactly is the error you get (exact text and stack trace please)?  What line of code does the error occur on?  You can get this info by changing `console.log("Error")` to `console.log(error)` so you are logging the actual error.  You should always log the actual error when troubleshooting problems as the actual error will give you clues about what went wrong.

Comment: TypeError: res.data.find is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (app.js:51:35)

Comment: why is your _app_ talking to axios? Your app talks to your server, your server talks to axios. So your app calls your server's URL for deleting something by id, and then it waits for the server to respond with "I have done what you asked me to". You app.js file should have zero axios code in it.

Comment: Well, there you go.  `res.data` is not what you think it is.  You will have to do `console.log(res.data)` and see what it actually is.

Comment: how do you suggest I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this:

```
const data = res.data.find((book) => book.id === Number(idValue));
```

needs to be changed to:

```
const data = res.data.data.find((book) => book.id === Number(idValue));
```

`res.data` is the axios response data and then you have a `data` element in your response that you need to get.  Your response is this:

```
return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: newBook });
```

so, `res.data` from axios gets you this `{ success: true, data: newBook }` so to get the `newBook` data, you need `res.data.data`.

---

FYI, all of this is basic debugging.  You log your exact error, follow the hints it gives you, then log other intermediate values to see where things went wrong and usually you can then see where the error is.